# Create a child element under a particular parent Xml Python

Tags: python, xml

I have an Xml file that I want to update, an extract from it:

```
<aircrafts>
  <aircraft designator="A148" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov An-148">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A148KOR" name="Air Koryo (KOR)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148AGU" name="Angara Airlines (AGU)"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft> 
</aircrafts>
```

I want to add a new texture entry only if the designator of the aircraft entry is `A148` for example in order to have an output like this:

```
<aircrafts>
  <aircraft designator="A148" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov An-148">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A148KOR" name="Air Koryo (KOR)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148AGU" name="Angara Airlines (AGU)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148LNR" name="Lun'Air (LNR)"/> #new texture entry
    </textures>
  </aircraft> 
</aircrafts>
```

There is my code but I didn't manage to do what I wanted:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('X-Plane 11/Resources/plugins/ivao_pilot/PilotUI/data/mtlList.xml') #File where the extract is located
tree = tree.getroot()



print(tree[0].tag)
for i in range(100):
    if tree[i].attrib['designator'] == "A148":
        a = ET.SubElement(
                tree[i], 
                "texture",
                attrib={
            "mtl_name": "A148LNR",
            "name": "Lun'Air (LNR)"}

        )
ET.dump(tree)
```

The XML is contained in a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aircrafts>
  <aircraft designator="A10" manufacturer="Fairchild Republic" name="Fairchild Republic A-10 Thunderbolt II">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A10" name="US Air Force"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft>
  <aircraft designator="A124" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov An-124 Ruslan">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A124" name="Antonov Design Bureau (ADB)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A124MXU" name="Maximus Air Cargo (MXU)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A124POT" name="Polet Air Company (POT)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A124RFF" name="Russian Federation Air Force (RFF)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A124VDA" name="Volga-dnepr (VDA)"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft>
  <aircraft designator="A148" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov An-148">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A148KOR" name="Air Koryo (KOR)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148AGU" name="Angara Airlines (AGU)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148ADB" name="Antonov Design Bureau (ADB)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148CUB" name="Cubana (An-158) (CUB)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148POT" name="Polet Air Company (POT)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148SDM" name="Rossiya (SDM)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148RFF" name="Russian Federation Air Force (RFF)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148SOV" name="Saratov Airlines (SOV)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148UKN" name="Ukraine Air Enterprise (UKN)"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft>
  <aircraft designator="A225" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov An-225 Mriya">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A225" name="Antonov Design Bureau (2010) (ADB)"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft>
<aircrafts>
```

Thanks a lot for helping and I hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
aircrafts = """<aircrafts>
  <aircraft designator="B100" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov Bn-248">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="B148KOR" name="Air Koryo (KOR)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="B148AGU" name="Angara Airlines (AGU)"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft> 
  <aircraft designator="A148" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov An-148">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A148KOR" name="Air Koryo (KOR)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148AGU" name="Angara Airlines (AGU)"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft> 
</aircrafts>
"""
```

I would do the following:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(aircrafts)
new_texture = etree.fromstring('<texture mtl_name="A148LNR" name="Lun\'Air (LNR)"/>')
for aircraft in doc.xpath('//aircraft[@designator="A148"]'):
    destination = aircraft.xpath('./textures')[0]
    destination.insert(2,new_texture)
    
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<aircrafts>
  <aircraft designator="B100" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov Bn-248">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="B148KOR" name="Air Koryo (KOR)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="B148AGU" name="Angara Airlines (AGU)"/>
    </textures>
  </aircraft> 
  <aircraft designator="A148" manufacturer="Antonov" name="Antonov An-148">
    <textures>
      <texture mtl_name="A148KOR" name="Air Koryo (KOR)"/>
      <texture mtl_name="A148AGU" name="Angara Airlines (AGU)"/>
    <texture mtl_name="A148LNR" name="Lun'Air (LNR)"/></textures>
  </aircraft> 
</aircrafts>
```

Comment: It works like a charm but there is a little problem, the new texture entry appears at the same line as an already existing texture line.

Comment: @Bastien1533 I don't see it on my system; my output is exactly as in the answer.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to parse from a file and can't figure how to convert the file to a string without having a charmap error. Thanks btw

Comment: @Bastien1533 I'm afraid I can't help with that since I don't have the whole file. If it's important enough, you may want to post another question with a short, representative sample of the file and maybe someone can help.

Comment: sorry for not including it. I just added it in the post.